# MySQL, Average every 30 inputs by timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, average

Hi i have a game were the users have 30 questions and i want to give them their AVG score(per match of 30 questions) and the history of all scores done before as well.

The collected data to exploit in my database is:

- score per question(0% to 100%),
- timestamps
- user_id

so the result in the DB is like houndreds of inputs where sometimes the user didn't reach to answer the 30 answers every time(maybe he turn off the app or got bored).

###### How to solve these?

My theory to solve these problem is to make groups by similar timestamps where the ***limit per groups is 30 inputs*** and per group i'll have an output of average score... Like that from 300inputs i"ll have 10outputs to exploit for front-end devs.

in case if its not clear i made an image explaining the DB i have(red) and the output i need(green)

[image]

###### What do you think? is these possible to do only in MySQL ??

Comment: Sorry, you question not so clear for me. Can you post your tables, test data and desired result. [mre]

Comment: What do you think about the image à made ? is more clear now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try next query as solution:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, DATE(answered_at),
    SUM(score>50) AS answers_above_50,
    COUNT(*) answers_count,
    AVG(score) average_score
FROM answers
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(answered_at);
```

[sql online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/edc678bd1c81452f7454d2cccaa33e77/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What do you mean for question_id ?

Comment: @Momo, sorry missprint